# Can not insert data into mongodalab collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I just start use Node.JS , try to connect to MongodbLab , I follow the doc http://docs.mongolab.com/#connect
but can not insert any data in my collection "team" the error keep saying   TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined , I google for 2 hrs ,Help please.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uri = "mongodb://awei:RRRRR@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.createConnection(uri);
 // we're connected!
 var db = mongoose.connection;
 db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));
 db.once('open', function() {

  });

db.team.insert({ "name" : "Awei" });
```

error

```
c:\Users\awei\WebstormProjects\untitled\app.js:22
db.team.insert({ "name" : "Awei" });
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\awei\WebstormProjects\untitled\app.js:22:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
at startup (node.js:140:18)
at node.js:1001:3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I am seeing, you need to connect with a username and password. See this:

http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/

under "Finding your database connection info".

In addition, MongoLab offers getting-started help for Node.js here:

http://docs.mongolab.com/languages/

Once you are actually connected to the database, you should be able to insert data to the team collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a pre-existing collection without the model using the mongoose connection's db object as follows:

```
var uri = "mongodb://awei:RRRRR@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.connect(uri);
var conn = mongoose.connection,
    db = conn.db;
conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));
conn.on('open', function() {
    console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
    db.collection("team", function (err, collection) {
        collection.insert({ "name" : "Awei" }, function(err, result){
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: THank you , but it didn't work , the console did't show (mongodb is connected) and i check the collection , didn't have any data q_q