# Can not get data from MongoDB in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to build some Web Api to get data from MongodbLab ,I can call the api and reply string now , but can't not get data from mongodb , I follow many tutorial try for three hours , but the web and  curl always reply [ empty reply from server ] , I believe is this part have some issue  `exports.findAll = function(req, res) {...}`, please help

code

```
var express = require('express'),
songs = require('./routes/route');

var app = express();


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
 console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

app.get('/songs',songs.findAll);
```

route

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var uri = "mongodb://1111:aaaa@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.connect(uri);
// we're connected!
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));

db.once('open', function() {
console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
});

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {              
db.collection('songs',function(err, collection) { 
collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {   
  res.send(items);
});
});
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not insert data into mongodalab collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414098/can-not-insert-data-into-mongodalab-collection)

Comment: Do you have data in your db? Does the console say connected?

Comment: yes , I have data in db and console also show connected

Comment: @chridam the question I ask was solved , it was an insert issue , and this time is a out put issue , just start use nodejs and mongodb , have a hard time;((

Comment: The other answer has got what you need. Here, you want to access the underlying collection with the connection object which is not possible, you need to get it from the db object of the connection i.e. `db = mongoose.connection.db` as shown in that answer.

Comment: @chridam wow IT WORKS! thanks! but I don't know why?
because I connect to the db already at 'db.once('open', function() {console.log("mongodb is connected!!");});' why need to 'db = mongoose.connection.db' confuse me

Comment: The variable nomenclature is the one that is confusing you, you are naming the connection object `db` instead of something that's appropriate for a connection object like e.g `var conn = mongoose.connection;`, as described in that previous answer once again. The `db` object is the one that has the underlying collection object, not the connection object as thus you can get it from `var db = conn.db; db.collection( ... )` etc

Comment: Oh!!!! It's really CLEAR now , you help me a lot! Thank you 100 times , I can sleep tight now :D